# Build Pulseaudio-11.1 and intltool >= 0.35.0 bug

Tags: linux, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, makefile, pulseaudio

Im trying to build pulseaudio-11.1 because firefox asks for it to play audio on video.

Im using knoppix 8.1, 64 bit installation, but it runs in 32bits.

When I configure the pulseaudio source, I get a message stating that intltool is too old. Despite having met their version requirement at 0.35.0. I installed from source version 0.51.0 and 0.50.2 but neither installation satisfied the demand. I get the same message at the end when I run bootstrap.sh

```
root@kami:/Downloads/pulseaudio-11.1# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... //bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '0' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '0' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for stow... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... //bin/grep
checking for egrep... //bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for gm4... no
checking for m4... m4
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE  in m/^(.*)\${ <-- HERE ?([A-Z_]+)}?(.*)$/ at /usr/local/bin/intltool-update  line 1064.
checking for intltool >= 0.35.0...  found
configure: error: Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.35.0 or  later.
```

This was before and after I removed version 0.35.0 of intltool that was pre-installed and then installed the newer versions, 0.51.0, then 0.50.2 to try a slightly older version if there was something wrong with the newest release, which is ironically quite old dating back to 2015.

Also bizarrly to top it off as you can see in the output before stating that the version is too old that it had found exactly what it is saying it does not have.

So in conclusion pulseaudio asks for intltool >= 0.35.0 which it finds and says right afterwards that it has not, which remained true across 3 seperate instances that satisfied their request on version 0.35.0, 0.51.0 and 0.50.2

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to ask Knoppix dot com too, they might be able to help. It's strange that you get 32 bit Linux, are you sure your Cpu is 64 bit?

Comment: Yes my cpu is definitely 64bits capable. This is standard on knoppix from what I have read, they do not have a full 64bit operating system.

Comment: It seems to me that the newer tool doesn't get intltool installed correctly. Are you using a LiveUSB Knoppix?

Comment: No a HDD installation

Comment: I managed to get the 64bit kernel loading, which isnt configured by default on knoppix. You have to update-grub in terminal, then edit the menu list in /boot for the kernel parameters, specifically relating to the root directory as the same for the default installation (/dev/sda1 or 2 usually).

Answer (score 0):

At installation 'NetworkManager-l2tp-master' i stumbled upon an error:
`configure: error: Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.35 or later`.
I used intermediate commands:

1. `./configure`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt install intltool imagemagick libmagickcore-dev pstoedit libpstoedit-dev`
4. `git clone https://github.com/autotrace/autotrace.git`
5. `cd autotrace`
6. `#unnecessary command for clarification should bugs be introduced later`
7. `git rev-parse HEAD`
8. `#t86c9c80c4h669302cb2571c0cab0rer7a102731`
9. `./autogen.sh`
10. `cd ..` # **necessarily** exit from 'autotrace' directory
11. `autoreconf -i`
12. `./configure` # again

after that, the error is resolved and indicates to:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.4) were not met:
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

This alert indicates that possible it is not installed pkg-config (corresponding version of Linux).